# Titaniuim: Facebook login event doesn't fire

Tags: ios, facebook, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am trying to login through facebook.
I have all info in plist and in entitlelements file
So when I click to button it is redirecting safari facebook page and asking to confirm
When I click to OK it doesn’t fire ‘login’ event and it is not logged.

Currently I am testing on iOS 5s Simulator

Here is the code

```
   var fbook = require('facebook');
   fbook.appid = <MyAPP_ID>;
   fbook.permissions = ['public_profile']; 
   //fbook.forceDialogAuth = true;


   if (fbook.loggedIn) {
       //progress.hide();
       params = {
           access_token : fbook.accessToken
       };
       fbook.requestWithGraphPath('/me', params, 'GET', function(e) {
           var result = JSON.parse(e.result)
       });
   } else {     
          fbook.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
           //alert('try to login');
           if (e.success) {
               //progress.hide();
               params = {
                   access_token : fbook.accessToken
               };
               fbook.requestWithGraphPath('/me', params, 'GET', function(e) {

                   var result = JSON.parse(e.result);
                   Ti.API.info("Result is : " + e.result);
                                  });
           } else if (e.error) {
               Ti.API.info("error");
               //alert('Error: ' + e.error);
           } else if (e.cancelled) {
               Ti.API.info("cancelled");
           }

       });

       fbook.authorize();
       /*
       fbook.addEventListener('logout', function(e) {
           fbook.logout();
       });*/

   }
```

Comment: I found solution. I should have this fbook.initialize()

Comment: add your solution as an answer (describe it a bit too) and mark it as solved there to help future people finding this question